# Python Pisa shrunk text in table

Tags: python-2.7, pisa

I am working on a work related problem and I seem to have got stuck on HTML to PDF conversion. I have an XML that is being converted to HTML and this HTML file has a portion of text which looks like

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> Large amount of text. Large enough to not fit on a page
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

There is nothing much that I can do with the HTML here. 
So the problem is when I use Pisa to convert HTML to PDF this text gets shrunk to fit on one single page. I tried using CSS tags like

```
table {
-pdf-keep-in-frame-mode: Overflow
}
```

but as soon as I use this property in the CSS irrespective of the behavior    (shrink, truncate,overflow, error) it always just shrinks further more. I have tried to use

tags within the  but they didn't help either. 
Basically I have tried almost everything that I could find online but nothing helped. Can someone please guide me on this. 
I am sorry i can't post the code here because its a work related problem

Thank you